# preg_match return all parts in array

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I've got following php code:

```
$match = array();
if (preg_match("%^(/\d+)(/test)(/\w+)*$%", "/25/test/t1/t2/t3/t4", $match))
    print_r($match);
```

I'm getting this result:

```
Array ( [0] => /25/test/t1/t2/t3/t4 [1] => /25 [2] => /test [3] => /t4 )
```

What do i need to change in my regexp to get this result:

```
Array ( [0] => /25/test/t1/t2/t3/t4 [1] => /25 [2] => /test [3] => /t1 [4] => /t2 [5] => /t3  [6] => /t4)
```

Comment: Could you please add the code that produces the results?

Comment: @Peter Stuifzand, sure, i edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need preg_match_all

```
preg_match_all( '~(/\w+)~', $str, $matches );
```

in your situation you can use explode too

Comment: sorry, i think i didnt make my question clear enough. i updated it with one more example. and explode isnt really a solution here, because i can also have string like this: /1:2:3:4 etc, so i'm generating my regular expression in php depending on some parameters i get.

Comment: :) yeah, but that's not really the solution i'm searching for. now i doubt it exists :)

Comment: well it gives the exact result you posted that you want, so you should update your question.

Comment: Your code works in one type of situation and shows the problem with testing. You also need to check the counter-examples as to be able to say it works right.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $str = '/a/b/1/2/3/4';
    if(preg_match('/^(\/\w+)*$/', $str) && preg_match_all('/\/\w+/', $str, $matches)) {
        $matches = $matches[0];
        print_r($matches);
    }

?>
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /a
    [1] => /b
    [2] => /1
    [3] => /2
    [4] => /3
    [5] => /4
)
```

Comment: That's not the solution i would like to use either :( so i can't make preg_match output all (\w+)*, only the last one?

Comment: @Denis, no you can't. Why does this solution not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Using your original example, you could use a recursive expression:

```
"%(/\w+)(?>[^(/\w+)]?|(?R))%"
```

This works my matching (/\w+) subexpressions in turn. Therfore the match for

```
"/a/b/1/2/3/4"
```

Would be:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => /a [1] => /b [2] => /1 [3] => /2 [4] => /3 [5] => /4
    )
...
```

However your later examples complicate things. A simple 0 or more match will only return the last (greedy) or first (ungreedy) match - not all submatches. preg_match_all won't be able to handle your dynamic expression.

You will have to clarify what you're trying to achieve in more detail before a suitable solution can be provided.

Comment: what i'm trying to archive: i've got a string, and i want to test it with regexp, and split into parts. i want to do it all in one preg_match (or preg_match_all), and i need splited parts to be in same order they apeard in original string. i'm generating regular expressions on some conditions i'm give, e.g.: (/<some_number>)(-<some_word>)(/<some_number>)*, the last one repeats zero or more times (it also can be in the middle of the string and repeat from 2 to 5 times, etc). I do can test the string with preg_match, and then manually split it, but i was searching for a nicer way to do it.

Comment: i just thought it's as simple as add some character to my regulat expression :)